A property of the exponential map on flat torus
Let $\mathbb{T}^n$ be the flat torus defined as $\{ z \in \mathbb{C}^n \colon z = (e^{i\theta_1}, \ldots, e^{i \theta_n}), \ \theta \in \mathbb{R}^n \}$ endowed with its standard Riemannian metrics. The exponential map on $\mathbb{T}^n$ is then given by $\exp (p, X) = ( e^{i (\theta_1 + X_1)}, \ldots, e^{i (\theta_n + X_n)} )$ for $p = ( e^{i\theta_1}, \ldots, e^{i \theta_n} ) \in \mathbb{T}^n$ and $X \in T_p \mathbb{T}^n \cong \mathbb{R}^n$.  This exponential map may be represented as follows:
$$
\exp(p, X) = \psi( \psi^{-1} (p) + X),
\quad \text{where} \quad
\psi \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{T}^n \colon
\psi(\theta) = ( e^{i \theta_1}, \ldots, e^{i \theta_n} ).
\tag{A}
$$
The questions I'm about to ask seems like something very obvious and standard, but I cannot find an explicit answer in the books on Riemannian geometry.

How does the property (A) relate to flatness?
If we forget about tori for a moment, what does being able to describe $\exp(p, X)$ on a given Riemannian manifold $(M, g)$ by the formula $\exp(p, X) = \psi( \psi^{-1} (p) + X )$ with some other map $\psi \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to N$ mean?
Are there other manifolds whose exponential maps satisfy this?


The problem is that you are using a presentation of the torus that obscures the simplicity of the issue.  I would suggest that you use the (equivalent) presentation of the torus as a suitable fundamental domain with identifications along the boundary, such as the domain $[0.2\pi]\times\cdots\times[0,2\pi]\subseteq\mathbb R^n$.
Another way of looking at it in your presentation: the metric on the circle is defined by the quadratic form $d\theta_i^2$.  When you take the Cartesian product of circles, by definition the resulting metric is defined by the quadratic form $d\theta_1^2+\cdots+d\theta_n^2$.  The latter quadratic form is by definition the quadratic form defining the flat metric.

This is not so much a question about torus... I am more interested in whether the representation of the exponential map as $\exp(p, X) = \psi( \psi^{-1}(p) + X )$ is some known property. I have found similar notions under the name of homogenous geodesics. I'm not completely sure what problem are you referring to...

I was answering your questions 1 and 3.

I understand that my torus is isometric to $\mathbb{R}^d / \mathbb{Z}^d$, yes, and the property is inherited from $\mathbb{R}^d$. I was wondering whether the property itself is related to flatness.

For example, $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ with $\exp(p, X) = p , \cos |X| + \frac{X}{|X|} , \sin |X|$ doesn't seem to have this property...

The property says that the exponential map is essentially the identity map of $\mathbb R^n$.  This certainly implies flatness.

But does some kind of flatness imply this property?
